# Java Regex pattern to match String from all languages that end with a whitespace

Tags: java, regex

Basically, I need to match words that start with a character from a string. The following is an example:

```
I am trying to match #this_word but ignore the rest.
```

I also need the regex to match characters from different languages. I tried this:

```
#\\s*(\\w+)
```

but err, it only includes English words.

When I try regex such as the followed:

```
#(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+
```

I get an `outofboundsexception`.

### Edit

Apparently the reason I used to get that error was because I wrote:

```
 matcher.group(1);
```

Instead of:

```
 matcher.group(0);
```

Comment: Use `#(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+`

Comment: @stribizhev this gave me the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, I think the error is from `p{L}` because when I tried that alone, it gave me the same error.

Comment: Could you please post the string that you have problem with?

Comment: Tbh, the string will change every time I use the method that extracts the substring (based on the regex I've chosen) each time. So, regardless what my string is, I am hoping to find a regex pattern that will work with any language and extract the word I want.

Comment: Here is [my demo](http://ideone.com/hrYByy).

Comment: @stribizhev Appreciate it! figured what was causing my error: Instead of matcher.group(0); I wrote matcher.group(1); Thanks!

Comment: I posted this and some more possible solutions as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care about digits, just add a [`(?U)` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) before the pattern:

> **`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`**
>   `public static final int UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`
>   Enables the Unicode version of *Predefined character classes* and *POSIX character classes*.
>   When this flag is specified then the (US-ASCII only) Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes are in conformance with [Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) Annex C: Compatibility Properties.
>
> The `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?U)`.
>
> The flag implies `UNICODE_CASE`, that is, it enables Unicode-aware case folding.

Regex:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?U)#\\w+");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wf2b9X)

You can actually subtract digits from `\w` with `[\\w&&[^\\d]]` to only match underscores and Unicode letters:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("#[\\w&&[^\\d]]+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

[Another demo](http://ideone.com/IaHt14)

As an alternative, to match any Unicode letter you may use `\p{L}\p{M}*+` subpattern (`\p{L}` is a base letter and `\p{M}` matches diacritics). So, to match only letters after `#` you can use `#(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+`.

To also support match an underscore, add it as an alternative: `#(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+|_)+`.

If you do not care about where the diacritic is, use just a character class: `#[\p{L}\p{M}_]+`.

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hrYByy):

```
String str = "I am trying to match #эту_строку but ignore the rest.";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("#(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+|_)+");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to capture all Unicode letters (matched by `\p{L}` class):

```
String ss="I am trying to match #this_word but ignore the rest.";
        Matcher m =Pattern.compile("#(\\p{L})+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(ss);
        while (m.find()) {            
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

Comment: This only matched English characters tho, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it covers all Unicode characters. Please read [the documentation on Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): >> Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
 #[^\s]+
```

This might work. It will match every non-spaced characters in the given String..